# S.M.A.R.T Status of ServeRAID M5015 on Lenny?

Tags: debian, raid, ibm, debian-lenny, smart

any experience with checking smart status of a ServeRAID M5015 under debian 5 lenny?

thanks!

Comment: what for raid controller does it have? a lsi megaraid?

Comment: yeah, it's a lsi megaraid!

Answer (score 1):

From the man page (change the detials to suite your setup):

```
smartctl -a -d megaraid,0 /dev/sdb
```